# Utilizar variables definidas en otro archivo PHP

Tags: php, html

estoy tratando de poner las variables con las que haré mí conexión a mí base de datos en un archivo aparte. El archivo es así (he omitido contraseñas y nombres para hacer la pregunta):

**connection.php:**

```
define ( 'DB_HOST', 'localhost');
define ( 'DB_USER', '******');
define ( 'DB_PASSWORD', '******');
define ( 'DB_NAME', '******');
```

Y luego el archivo con el que uso este código es el siguiente.
**registroUsuario.php:**

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/connection.php';

//creacion de la conexion
$conn = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD) or die("Fallo en la conexión");
$db = mysqli_select_db($conn,DB_NAME) or die("No se selecciona la DB");


//cogiendo variables
    $mail = $_POST['mail'];
    $usrName = $_POST['usuario'];
    $passUsr = $_POST['pass'];
    $date = $_POST['fecha'];
    $name = $_POST['nombre'];
    $apUno = $_POST['apellidoUno'];
    $apDos = $_POST['apellidoDos'];

    $farmOrClient = $_POST['farmOcliente'];
    $nssOrLicence = $_POST['nssOrLicence'];

    //password encrypting
    $encPass = password_hash($passUsr,PASSWORD_DEFAULT);



    //sentencia sql y ejecución de esta
    $sql = mysqli_prepare($conn,"INSERT INTO Usuario VALUES('$mail','$usrName','$encPass','$date','$name','$apUno','$apDos')");
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($sql, "s", $mail, $usrName, $passUsr, $date, $name, $apUno, $apDos);

    mysqli_stmt_execute($sql);
    echo 'Bat';
    if($farmOrClient == "farm"){

            $sql = mysqli_prepare($conn,"INSERT INTO Duenio VALUES('$mail','$nssOrLicence')");
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($sql, "s", $mail, $nssOrLicence);
            mysqli_stmt_execute($sql) or die('Txarto');
            echo('Ondo');

    }else if($farmOrClient == "client"){
            $sql = mysqli_prepare($conn,"INSERT INTO Paciente VALUES('$mail','$nssOrLicence')");
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($sql, "s", $mail, $nssOrLicence);
            mysqli_stmt_execute($sql) or die('Txarto');
            echo('Ondo');

    }

    //cerrando la conexíon
    mysqli_close($conn);
```

El problema está en que hace la conexión bien, pero al ejecutar la sentencia de sql falla.

Me gustaría añadir que cuando en vez del include defino las variables como locales funciona. Para hacer la prueba he usado este formulario:

**pruebaRegistro.html:**

```html
<html>
 <head>
        <title>Prueba</title>
 </head>
 
 <body>
  <form action="registroUsuario.php" method="post">
      <div>
             <label for="mail">E-mail:</label>
    <input type="text" id="mail" name="mail"/>         
      </div>
 
   <div>
    <label for="usuario">Usuario:</label>
    <input type="text" id="usuario" name="usuario"/>
   </div>
   <div>
    <label for="pass">Contraseña:</label>
    <input type="text" id="pass" name="pass"/>
   </div>
    
   <div>
    <label for="fecha">Fecha:</label>
    <input type="text" id="fecha" name="fecha"/>
   </div>
    
    <div>
    <label for="nombre">Nombre:</label>
    <input type="text" id="nombre" name="nombre"/>
   </div>
    
   <div>
    <label for="apellidoUno">Primer Apellido:</label>
    <input type="text" id="apellido1" name="apellidoUno"/>
   </div>
   
   <div>
    <label for="apellidoDos">Segundo Apellido:</label>
    <input type="text" id="apellido2" name="apellidoDos"/>
   </div>
    
            <div>
                <label for="farmOcliente">Cliente o keloke:</label>
    <input type="text" id="farmOcliente" name="farmOcliente"/>
            </div>
    
                <div>
                <label for="nssOrLicence">Mete tu shit:</label>
    <input type="text" id="nssOrLicence" name="nssOrLicence"/>
            </div>
    
   <div class="button">
    <button type="submit">Send your message</button>
   </div>


   </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

El resultado es este:

```html
Warning: mysqli_stmt_bind_param() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, boolean given in /storage/ssd5/279/3001279/public_html/PHP/registroUsuario.php on line 28

Warning: mysqli_stmt_execute() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, boolean given in /storage/ssd5/279/3001279/public_html/PHP/registroUsuario.php on line 30
Bat
Warning: mysqli_stmt_bind_param() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, boolean given in /storage/ssd5/279/3001279/public_html/PHP/registroUsuario.php on line 35

Warning: mysqli_stmt_execute() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, boolean given in /storage/ssd5/279/3001279/public_html/PHP/registroUsuario.php on line 36
Txarto
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema está aqui: `$sql = mysqli_prepare($conn,"INSERT INTO Usuario VALUES('$mail','$usrName','$encPass','$date','$name','$apUno','$apDos')");`, al ser una sentencia preparada debería ser algo asi:

```
$sql = mysqli_prepare($conn,"INSERT INTO Usuario VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($sql, "sssssss", $mail, $usrName, $passUsr, $date, $name, $apUno, $apDos);
```

Las `sssssss` se corresponden con el tipo de dato que vas a introducir en la sentencia.

Puedes ver más sobre sentencias preparadas [aqui](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp) o [aqui](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

EDIT: No solo está el error en esa sentencia, en las siguientes(las que están dentro de los `if`) también hay este fallo. Si vas a las docs de las sentencias preparadas encontrarás información para poder aplicar las sentencias preparadas correctamente.

Comment: El fallo no está en esa consulta, si no en las siguientes, las que dependen de esta condicion if($farmOrClient == "farm")

Comment: Se me ha pasado añadirlo, pero están igual de mal todas, ya que hace lo mismo en todas, edito la respuesta :) @MikelMolinuevo

Comment: Ya he probado a cambiarlas y no es ese el error. Como digo arriba al definir las variables en el mismo archivo y hacer todo con esas variables locales si que funciona, así que el problema no es con las consultas si no con la manera en la que se utilizan las variables

Comment: Se ejecuta el `echo('Bat');`? @MikelMolinuevo

Comment: Si se ejecuta, luego ya sale 'Txarto'. Ahora añado foto del error

Comment: Cambie el `or die('Txarto');` de manera que sea distinto en los dos ifs, para ver cual es el que se ejecuta y, por favor, enséñeme el código actualizado tras arreglar el error mencionado en la respuesta

Comment: Da igual cual de las dos condiciones se ejecuta, en este caso por lo que paso desde el formulario se ejecuta cuando $farmOrClient == "farm". Da el mismo error si se le pasa el otro

Comment: Pruebe a mostrar con un `echo` el contenido de las variables, el error que muestra es que aportas un valor booleano(true/false) a la función, habría que identificar cual es la variable exacta que produce ese error @MikelMolinuevo

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78375/discussion-between-alex55132-and-mikel-molinuevo).

Comment: Lo he conseguido al final y tenías razón, las consultas estaban mal hechas. Muchas gracias